# Save wordpress user ID in session, match the ID to a form input, then authenticate user, PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication, session, session-variables

I know PIN login in wordpress is still an issue, but we can always try. Am trying to achieve the same by:
**Step 1:** Storing user ID(or may be username) in WP session after the user completes registration.During registration, users can create a PIN, which is stored as meta. This meta field is also stored in the session alongside user ID.
**Step 2:** Create a login form with one input field called "PIN", and a submit button.
**Step 3:** When a user (who already registered from the same device) enters PIN, php matches the entered PIN with the PIN stored in session, then authenticates the user with ID stored in the same session. DONE!

I just need to achieve this for now, I will handle logout in a different area.Also, please leave the security questions out of this for now. Just help me achieve it.

I got this code, which is now the basis of my approach. But as you can see, it compared the USERNAME entered in the input to usernames in the database to authenticate users. I could just do the same with a meta field called "PIN" instead of USERNAME, but the problem is, two or more users can set a similar PIN, and find themeselves logged in to accounts that don't belong to them. This is why I have to store the ID in session, alongsite the user meta called PIN. Then make sure the PIN entered by user matches the PIN stored in session alongside his user ID. Then autenticate the user ID stored in session.

```
    global $user_id;
    global $wpbd; 
    if (!$user_ID){

        if($_POST){ //when form is submitted
            $username = $wpdb->escape($_POST['username']);
            $user = get_user_by( 'login', $username );
            if ( $user === false ) {
                    echo 'no'; // add error message
            } else {
                    //user id exists
                    wp_set_current_user($user->ID, $user->user_login);
                    wp_set_auth_cookie($user->ID);
                    
                    // redirect to admin-area:
                wp_redirect( home_url() );
                    exit();
            }
        } else {
        
            // user is not log in ?>
        <form method="post">
            <p>
                <label for="username">User ID</label>
                <input type="text" id="userame" name="username" placeholder="User ID">
            </p>
            <p>
                <button type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">Log IN</button>
            </p>
        </form>
        <?php }
        } else {
            wp_redirect( home_url() );
        }
     ?>
```

Comment: Are you sure you want a session for this? Session data is temporary and will be lost fairly quickly. Wouldn’t a cookie be a better place to stash the username? Also, is there a reason you can’t just use the native password to hold the PIN? You can relax requirements for complexity and WordPress will take care of the rest.

Comment: Hi @ChrisHaas, I also did some research and found out that indeed sessions will be lost as fast as the browser is closed. Am developing a webapp (android) and the website runs on wordpress. I dont want users to keep on inserting thier email and password each time so I would go with a PIN. If the native password holds the PIN, the user email will still be needed right?. That said, I think a cookie is the way to go, but i dont know how

Comment: As you’ve noted, a PIN by itself isn’t going to be unique so you really need a username, and as I’ve noted, a PIN is just a limited password. You can store the username in a cookie (or local storage) and effectively auto fill on the login form. You could also consider just using the “Remember Me” feature and [increase](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/188988/12496) the amount of time on it.

Comment: @ChrisHaas could you please show me how i can add a cookie script to the above ode. So that the cookie saves username from first login (permanently unless the device is changed). Then pass this saved username to the login form as shown in the code